# listview inside a dialog window manager bad token exception

Tags: android

I am working on an app where by clicking an image, a dialog has to open with a listview inside it. This image is also in a listview so the onClickListener is in the getView method of the adapter.

When i click on an image, the app stops giving me a WindowManagerBadTokenException on the dialog.show() line.

This is my code :

```
    public class HomeListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HomeItem>
{
    public Context context;
    public ArrayList<HomeItem> HomeItemList;
    //ArrayList<String> phone;

    public HomeListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<HomeItem> HomeItemLst) {
        super(context, resource, HomeItemLst);
        this.context = context;
        this.HomeItemList = HomeItemLst;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (HomeItemList != null)
            return HomeItemList.size();
      return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public HomeItem getItem(int position) {
        return HomeItemList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View myConvertView = null;
        try {
            final HomeItem HomeItem = HomeItemList.get(position);
            myConvertView = convertView;
            if (myConvertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                myConvertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.branches_list_item_view, null);
            }
            TextView CatHeader = (TextView) myConvertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView CatTitle = (TextView) myConvertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) myConvertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            CatHeader.setText(HomeItem.getHomeItemName());
            CatTitle.setText(HomeItem.getHomeItemDescription());

            imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int region = HomeItem.getHomeItemId();
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    builder.setTitle("Phone Numbers");
                    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_call);
                    ListView modeList = new ListView(context);
                    ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> branchesAllRegions = BranchesActivity.branchesAllRegions;

                    ArrayList<String> phone = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for(int i = 4 ; i < branchesAllRegions.get(region).get(position).size() ; i++)
                    {
                        phone.add(branchesAllRegions.get(region).get(position).get(i));
                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, phone);
                    modeList.setAdapter(modeAdapter);
                    builder.setView(modeList);
                    final Dialog dialog = builder.create();

                    dialog.show();
                    /*LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View v = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog_list, null, false);
                    dialog.setContentView(v);
                    dialog.show();*/
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return myConvertView;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

This is where i initialized my HomeListAdapter :

```
private void PopulateHomePageItemList(){
        adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(this);

        HomeItemList = new ArrayList<HomeItem>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < branchesAllRegions.get(0).size() ; i++){
            HomeItem homeItem = new HomeItem();
            homeItem.setHomeItemName(branchesAllRegions.get(0).get(i).get(0));
            homeItem.setHomeItemDescription(branchesAllRegions.get(0).get(i).get(1));
            homeItem.setHomeItemId(0);
            HomeItemList.add(homeItem);
        }
        HomeListAdapter = new  HomeListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 0, HomeItemList);
        if(HomeListAdapter!= null)
            adapter.addSection(regions.get(0), HomeListAdapter );


        HomeItemList = new ArrayList<HomeItem>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < branchesAllRegions.get(1).size() ; i++){
            HomeItem homeItem = new HomeItem();
            homeItem.setHomeItemName(branchesAllRegions.get(1).get(i).get(0));
            homeItem.setHomeItemDescription(branchesAllRegions.get(1).get(i).get(1));
            homeItem.setHomeItemId(1);
            HomeItemList.add(homeItem);
        }
        HomeListAdapter = new  HomeListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 0, HomeItemList);
        if(HomeListAdapter!= null)
            adapter.addSection(regions.get(1), HomeListAdapter );


        HomeItemList = new ArrayList<HomeItem>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < branchesAllRegions.get(2).size() ; i++){
            HomeItem homeItem = new HomeItem();
            homeItem.setHomeItemName(branchesAllRegions.get(2).get(i).get(0));
            homeItem.setHomeItemDescription(branchesAllRegions.get(2).get(i).get(1));
            homeItem.setHomeItemId(2);
            HomeItemList.add(homeItem);
        }
        HomeListAdapter = new  HomeListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 0, HomeItemList);
        if(HomeListAdapter!= null)
            adapter.addSection(regions.get(2), HomeListAdapter );

        HomeItemList = new ArrayList<HomeItem>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < branchesAllRegions.get(3).size() ; i++){
            HomeItem homeItem = new HomeItem();
            homeItem.setHomeItemName(branchesAllRegions.get(3).get(i).get(0));
            homeItem.setHomeItemDescription(branchesAllRegions.get(3).get(i).get(1));
            homeItem.setHomeItemId(3);
            HomeItemList.add(homeItem);
        }
        HomeListAdapter = new  HomeListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 0, HomeItemList);
        if(HomeListAdapter!= null)
            adapter.addSection(regions.get(3), HomeListAdapter );

        HomeItemList = new ArrayList<HomeItem>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < branchesAllRegions.get(4).size() ; i++){
            HomeItem homeItem = new HomeItem();
            homeItem.setHomeItemName(branchesAllRegions.get(4).get(i).get(0));
            homeItem.setHomeItemDescription(branchesAllRegions.get(4).get(i).get(1));
            homeItem.setHomeItemId(4);
            HomeItemList.add(homeItem);
        }
        HomeListAdapter = new  HomeListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 0, HomeItemList);
        if(HomeListAdapter!= null)
            adapter.addSection(regions.get(4), HomeListAdapter );

        HomeItemList = new ArrayList<HomeItem>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < branchesAllRegions.get(5).size() ; i++){
            HomeItem homeItem = new HomeItem();
            homeItem.setHomeItemName(branchesAllRegions.get(5).get(i).get(0));
            homeItem.setHomeItemDescription(branchesAllRegions.get(5).get(i).get(1));
            homeItem.setHomeItemId(5);
            HomeItemList.add(homeItem);
        }
        HomeListAdapter = new  HomeListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 0, HomeItemList);
        if(HomeListAdapter!= null)
            adapter.addSection(regions.get(6), HomeListAdapter );

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

This is the logcat :

```
08-18 10:43:25.949: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(15903): Parent view is not a TextView
08-18 10:44:09.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15903): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-18 10:44:09.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15903): Process: com.example.creditlibanais, PID: 15903
08-18 10:44:09.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15903): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
08-18 10:44:09.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15903):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:731)
08-18 10:44:09.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15903):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:278)
08-18 10:44:09.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15903):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
08-18 10:44:09.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15903):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:288)
08-18 10:44:09.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15903):    at com.example.creditlibanais.HomeListAdapter$1.onClick(HomeListAdapter.java:80)
08-18 10:44:09.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15903):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4626)
08-18 10:44:09.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15903):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19300)
08-18 10:44:09.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15903):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-18 10:44:09.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15903):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-18 10:44:09.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15903):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
08-18 10:44:09.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15903):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
08-18 10:44:09.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15903):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 10:44:09.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15903):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-18 10:44:09.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15903):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
08-18 10:44:09.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15903):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
08-18 10:44:09.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15903):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you post the whole class.

Comment: i edited my answer and posted the whole class

Comment: post the code where you initialized the `HomeListAdapter`

Comment: i added this part of the code

Comment: post compelete logcat !!!

Comment: it is posted already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is your **context** which you are using to show your AlertDialog , if you are using `getApplicationContext()` try changing it to your Activity context .

Edit :

change this line :

```
 HomeListAdapter = new  HomeListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 0, HomeItemList)
```

to :

```
 HomeListAdapter = new  HomeListAdapter(YourActivity.this, 0, HomeItemList)
```

Comment: @Arash This worked!! Thank you. But why did it work?

Comment: @Recomer : because Application context doesn't have any window for showing dialog so you have to provide activity context.